# Creating a basis tableuas in Latex

Tags: tables

I have to create a latex figure/table like below

[image]

I have figured out how to create tha table but I am having some trouble iwth the width of the columns and placing the top indices (i, j, k, l)

The code to create tables is as follows

```
    \begin{table}[h]
    \centering
     \renewcommand{\arraystretch}{2.2}  
     \begin{tabular}{|>{\centering\arraybackslash}p{.5cm}|>{\centering\arraybackslash}p{1.5cm}>{\centering\arraybackslash}p{1.5cm}>{\centering\arraybackslash}p{2cm}|}
                    \hline
                         &  &           & \\ \hline
                           &          &     & \\[-0.8cm]
                           &          & $\tau_{ij}$        & $\tau_{il}$\\[0.7cm]
                           &          &     & \\[-0.4cm]
                           &  & $\tau_{kj}$  & $\tau_{kl}$\\[1cm] \hline
                \end{tabular}
    \end{table}
```

Comment: Are you sure that this is the way you want your tables typeset? I don't think they're very typographically pleasant

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Add the two tables side-by-side like this:

```
\begin{table}[htbp]
    \centering
     \renewcommand{\arraystretch}{1.5}  
     \begin{tabular}{c|>{\centering\arraybackslash}p{.5cm}|@{\hspace{.5cm}}>{\centering\arraybackslash}p{1.5cm}>{\centering\arraybackslash}p{1.5cm}|c}
\multicolumn{1}{c}{}&\multicolumn{1}{c}{}&\multicolumn{1}{c}{$j$}   & \multicolumn{1}{c}{$l$} \\
                    \cline{2-4}
                         &    &             & &                     \\ \cline{2-4}
                         &    &             & &                     \\[-0.8cm]
                     $i$ &    & $\tau_{ij}$ & $\tau_{il}$ & pivot   \\[-.2cm]
                         &    &             & & $\Rightarrow$       \\[-.2cm]
                     $k$ &    & $\tau_{kj}$ & $\tau_{kl}$ & $(k,l)$ \\[.3cm] \cline{2-4}
    \end{tabular}
    \begin{tabular}{c|>{\centering\arraybackslash}p{.5cm}|@{\hspace{.5cm}}>{\centering\arraybackslash}p{1.5cm}>{\centering\arraybackslash}p{1.5cm}|}
\multicolumn{1}{c}{}&\multicolumn{1}{c}{}&\multicolumn{1}{c}{$j$} & \multicolumn{1}{c}{$k$} \\
                    \cline{2-4}
                         &    &                 &               \\ \cline{2-4}
                         &    &                 &               \\[-0.8cm]
                     $i$ &    & $\tau_{ij}'$    & $\tau_{ik}'$  \\[-.2cm]
                         &    &                 &               \\[-.2cm]
                     $l$ &    & $\tau_{\ell j}'$& $\tau_{lk}'$  \\[.3cm] \cline{2-4}
    \end{tabular}
\end{table}
```

[image]

Answer (score 2):

There many possibilities to achieve want you want, and the best one depends on where you finally want to get to. Here is a plain LaTeX solution.

[image]

```
\documentclass{article}
\begin{document}
\[\begin{array}[b]{c|c|cc|}
    \multicolumn{1}{c}{}
      & \multicolumn{1}{c}{}
        & j        & \multicolumn{1}{c}{\ell}
  \\\cline{2-4}
      & &          &
  \\\cline{2-4}
    i & & \tau_{ij} & \tau_{i\ell}
  \\
    k & & \tau_{kj} & \tau_{k\ell}
  \\\cline{2-4}
  \end{array}
  \quad
  \begin{array}[b]{c}
    \mathsf{pivot}\\
    \Longrightarrow\\
    (k,\ell)
  \end{array}
  \quad
  \begin{array}[b]{c|c|cc|}
    \multicolumn{1}{c}{}
         & \multicolumn{1}{c}{}
           & j            & \multicolumn{1}{c}{k}
  \\\cline{2-4}
         & &              &
  \\\cline{2-4}
    i    & & \tau_{ij}'    & \tau_{ik}'
  \\
    \ell & & \tau_{\ell j}' & \tau_{\ell k}'
  \\\cline{2-4}
  \end{array}
  \]
\end{document}
```